# Opening command prompt at Windows startup

Tags: cmd

I have an application that runs (listens to incoming TCP data) from the command prompt. How can I make the command prompt open at Windows Startup and get to the following:

**C:/wamp/php/php test.php**

where "test.php" is the file that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solutin to my own question: 
I created a batch file with commands that redirect to the file (c:\wamp\php\php test.php). I then pinned the file on the startup folder. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

add it to the startup folder (start menu).